# Umbraco 7: Copy Property from another Document Type

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, umbraco, umbraco7

My `Document Types` section structure is like this:

```
Master
  Home
  Common
```

**Q:** How can I copy a property from `Common` to `Home` so I can edit it in the Home `Content` and have it's own version of that property?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot copy properties in this way. You will have to re-create the property under the 'Home' document type manually. The best thing to do would be to add the property to the master (assuming you have no pages of this type) then the other two document types will inherit the property. This is provided that you dont have other document types as direct children of the master document type.

So we can look at it like this:

'+' = Document Type
'-' = Property

```
+Master
  -Title
  -Description
  +Home
    -Title(inherited from Master)
    -Description(inherited from Master)
    -Gallery (unique to Home document type)
  +Common
    -Title(inherited from Master)
    -Description(inherited from Master)
    -Photos (unique to Common document type)
    -Gallery (unique to Common document type)
```

In the example above, the gallery property is required for both the 'Home' and 'Common' document types. But, it is not necessarily valid for other children of the master template. We have therefore had to duplicate the property because we cannot add it to the master or the other templates would inherit the property too. Therefore to get around this (as dicussed in the comments below) you should do something like this:

```
'+' = Document Type
'-' = Property

+Master
  -Title (defined in Master)
  -Description (defined in Master)

  +Other
    -Title(inherited from Master)
    -Description(inherited from Master)

  +Test
    -Gallery(defined in Test)

    +Home
      -Title(inherited from Master)
      -Description(inherited from Master)
      -Gallery (inherited from Test)

    +Common
      -Title(inherited from Master)
      -Description(inherited from Master)
      -Photos (unique to Common document type)
      -Gallery (inherited from Test)
```

Comment: so I have to create it again in the master, and then delete it from Common? it is a pretty complex property...

Comment: Will the property be used on more than one page? If yes, then you should create a parent for the pages that it is used on. So if the property is only needed on Home and Common, you should create a child of the Master document type that has the properties you require then make the 'Home' and 'Common' templates children of this parent template.

Comment: No problem! Just so you know, questions like this might be best ask on ourumbraco the official Umbraco forums as the Umbraco usership here on Stack Overflow is fairly low.